# Chrome media cache always been deleted

Tags: google-chrome, caching, media

I encountered a problem under Chrome. I need to load a big MP4 file with video element. After call function "play" , the video's API told me that it is buffered, and I find the buffered file under Media Cache folder. However, when I set the video back to the start or any other position that already been played before, browser still send request to the server and the cache indeed be deleted under Media Cache folder. Any one can tell me why this happen, and how to prevent it?